# Higher order arithmetic and fragments of ZFC

Tags: proof-theory

Zbierski "Models for Higher Order Arithmetics" (BULL. DE L'ACAD. POLONAISE DES SCIENCES Serie des sciences math., astr. et phys. - Vol. XIX, No. 7, 1971) defines ZF$_n$ as ZFC with the power set axiom limited to $n$ successive power sets starting from the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.  Note this includes the axiom of choice.  He proves ZF$_n$  is a conservative extension of $n+2$ order arithmetic with the axiom scheme of choice..  He notes Gandy had proved already ZF$_2$  is not conservative over $4$th order arithmetic without the axiom scheme of choice.

But what is known about the case where the axiom of choice is also removed from ZF$_2$?

Sochor "Constructibility in higher order arithmetics" (Arch. Math. Logic (1993) 32:381-389) shows that $n$-th order arithmetic without choice can interpret  $n$-th order arithmetic with choice.though obviously it is not a conservative extension.    So the issue is not equiconsistency.  It is conservativity.

Comment: Since collection and replacement are no longer equivalent without full power set, could you clarify exactly what the theory is? e.g. http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/

Comment: Also, without power set, the various formulations of the axiom of choice are no longer equivalent.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins  Actually Zbierski is not explicit about those issues, and following the tradition of proof theory his proofs are telegraphic and rest heavily on what it is "easy to see."  So it is not easy to see exactly what axioms he has in mind for ZFC.   His arithmetic axiom scheme of choice says wherever a formula $F(x,y)$ relates every order $n$ set to at least one order $n+1$ set then there is some single order $n+1$ set $z$ collecting codes for order $n$ pairs such that each $x$ is $F$-related to the set $z^{(x)}$ of all $u$ such that code for $\langle x,u\rangle$ is in $z$.

Comment: That's a pity. The strongest natural formulation would be to use collection+separation, rather than merely replacement, plus the other usual axioms (union, extensionality, etc.) and to use the well-order principle instead of a choice function version of AC.

Comment: There is no way to express the well-orderability of the highest sort in $n$th order arithmetic without using an extra $(n+1)$th order relation symbol, or something to that effect. This is why the standard formulation of AC in higher-order arithmetic is the choice functions version.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I had understood the theory here to be expressed in the language of set theory, rather than in some context of higher-order number theory. Is that not what is meant?

Comment: There are two theories here, one is in the language of higher-order arithmetic, and one is in the language of set theory. Sorry if I was unclear; what I wrote applies to the arithmetical theory, whereas you were talking about the set theory. However, my point was that Colin McLarty’s comment describes what choice principle is postulated in the arithmetical theory, not necessarily (or even likely) in the set theory.

Comment: Zbierski is specific about choice in $\mathrm{ZFC}_n$ in this paper: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm112/fm112118.pdf

Comment: The replacement/collection issue is irrelevant to Zbierski. The goal is to show that every model of $(n+2)$-nd order arithmetic is the $(n+2)$-nd order arithmetical part of a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}_n$. All of this happens in sets of rank bounded $\omega+n+2$, where replacement/collection issues are nonexistent.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais The replacement/collection issue is relevant, since the replacement version of ZFC-P doesn't prove $\omega_1$ is regular, while the collection+separation version does, and this shows up at rank $\omega+2$. So unless I am misunderstanding, it is relevant for $\text{ZFC}_2$. But Zbierski's version of AC is stronger than both AC and WOP; it is analogous to what is called "class choice" (stronger than global AC), and in this context, replacement and collection become equivalent. I'm not sure, however, if this observation can be turned into an answer to the question.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Could you say what it means precisely to be "a model of $(n+2)$-order arithmetic"?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I should have been clearer: the replacement/collection issue has no bearing on the *conservativity* assertion. It does matter for the *extension* assertion. Is it plausible that for every model of $\mathrm{ZFC}-\mathrm{P}$, replacement form, where $V_{\omega+n}$ exists, there is a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}-\mathrm{P}$, collection form, with the same $V_{\omega+n}$? That doesn't seem to contradict anything I'm aware about this.

Comment: That extension claim is false, by the arguments in the ZFC-P paper I linked to in my comment above, since we can make the top cardinal singular in the replacement form, but not in the collection form. But that is assuming WOP version of AC. If you assume that strong form of AC as explained above, then this won't work anymore, since it amounts basically to collection instead of replacement at that level.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: You're right about the strong AC, which implies collection. But I'm not sure how your arguments from the ZFC-P paper apply. Specifically, I don't see how to get $\omega_1$ singular and having $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ exist.

Comment: Oh, I see that you were particular about $V_{\omega+n}$ existing (as a set). Our method only applies if you relax that. What they show that not every $V_{\omega+n+1}$ from a model of ZFC-P with reflection arises as a $V_{\omega+n+1}$ from a model of ZFC-P with collection+separation, even when $V_{\omega+n}$ exists as a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to prove something like this is to take a model of $(n+1)$-st order arithmetic $\mathcal{A}$ and interpret a model of set theory $\mathcal{V}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such a the usual interpretation of $(n+1)$-st order arithmetic in $\mathcal{V}$ leads to a model isomorphic to $\mathcal{A}$. There are a few recipes to do this, using graph, trees and other convenient encodings of sets. See the discussion [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set),  I will use wellfounded accessible pointed graphs (WAPGs), though Zbierski probably uses trees (I don't know since I haven't found the paper).

The model $\mathcal{A}$ of $(n+1)$-st order arithmetic has sorts $N = S_0,S_1,\ldots,S_n$, where $N$ is the number sort and each $S_{i+1}$ consists of subsets of the previous sort $S_i$. The number sort $N$ has the usual arithmetic structure with full induction for the implied language. Each sort $S_i$ ($i \geq 1$) has full comprehension within the implied language. I'll refrain from making choice assumptions to see how far things go. Each sort has a definable pairing function, so we can talk about tuples, relations and functions. In particular, we can talk about WAPGs coded in $S_n$.

The model $\mathcal{V}$ is obtained by collecting all WAPGs in the top sort $S_n$. Equality $G \equiv H$ between two WAPGs $G$ and $H$ is interpreted as the existence of a bisimulation between $G$ and $H$, and membership $G \in H$ is interpreted as the existence of a bisimulation between $G$ and an immediate subgraph $H/x$ of $H$. After quotienting by $\equiv$ if desired, the result is an interpretation of the language of set theory which is automatically extensional and wellfounded (in the internal sense). Furthermore, since WAPGs coded in $S_n$ and bisimulations between them are definable in $(n+1)$-th order arithmetic, every formula $\phi$ in the language of set theory has a translation $\phi^V$ in the language of $(n+1)$-th order arithmetic such that $\mathcal{V} \vDash \phi \iff \mathcal{A} \vDash \phi^V$.

Furthermore, we can define canonical WAPGs for each sort $\omega,\mathcal{P}(\omega),\ldots,\mathcal{P}^{n-1}(\omega)$. Specifically, the WAPG for $\omega$ is the graph of the ordering relation on the sort $N$; the WAPG for $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is built on top of that one by adding a node for each $X \in \mathcal{S}_1$ and linking it to its elements; etc. Using the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ has full comprehension and the translation, we see that each $\mathcal{P}^{i+1}(\omega)$ really is the powerset of the previous one as understood in $\mathcal{V}$. So the natural interpretation of the arithmetical sorts $\omega,\mathcal{P}(\omega),\ldots,\mathcal{P}^{n-1}(\omega)$ in $\mathcal{V}$ are canonically isomorphic to the original sorts $N,S_1,\ldots,S_{n-1}$ from $\mathcal{A}$. The top sort $\mathcal{P}^n(\omega)$ is not necessarily a set in $\mathcal{V}$ but it is a definable class. Again, full comprehension can be used to argue that $\mathcal{P}^n(\omega)$ is canonically isomorphic to the original top sort $S_n$.

So far, we haven't needed any choice; I only used full comprehension in $\mathcal{A}$. It remains to check which axioms $\mathcal{V}$ satisfies. Many are straightforward to check. We already checked extensionality, foundation and infinity. Pairing and union correspond to simple combinatorial manipulations of WAPGs. Comprehension follows from comprehension in $\mathcal{A}$. Replacement/collection are problematic without further assumptions about $\mathcal{A}$. There is a good reason for that since we have just shown one half of:

**Theorem.** *The theory $\mathrm{Z}^-_{n-1}$ (extensionality, foundation, pairing, union, comprehension and the existence of $\omega,\mathcal{P}(\omega),\ldots,\mathcal{P}^{n-1}(\omega)$) is a conservative extension of $(n+1)$-th order arithmetic (without choice).*

The missing half is the straightforward proof that $\mathrm{Z}^-_{n-1}$ is an extension of $(n+1)$-th order arithmetic. In other words, that the interpretation $N = \omega, S_1 = \mathcal{P}(\omega), \ldots, S_n = \mathcal{P}^n(\omega)$ always yields a model of $(n+1)$-th order arithmetic.

---

Here is a reason why some choice principles might be necessary. For simplicity, I will assume we are working in $2$-nd order arithmetic. I will show that if collection holds in $\mathcal{V}$ then countable choice holds in $\mathcal{A}$. Say $\phi(n,x)$ is a formula in $2$-nd order arithmetic that relates each natural number $n$ with a set $x$ of natural numbers. We can translate $\phi(n,x)$ to a synonymous formula $\psi(n,x)$ in $\mathcal{V}$ such that $(\forall n \in \omega)(\exists x \subseteq \omega)\psi(n,x)$. Every set in $\mathcal{V}$ is countable, by construction, so if there is a set $b \in \mathcal{V}$ such that $(\forall n \in \omega)(\exists x \in b)\psi(n,x)$, then back in $\mathcal{A}$ there is a countable sequence $\langle x_n \rangle$ coded in $S_1$ such that $\phi(n,x_n)$ holds for every $n$.

In a similar fashion, for any $n$, if $S_{n-1}$ is wellorderable in a model $\mathcal{A}$ of $(n+1)$-st order arithmetic, then collection in $\mathcal{V}$ gives choice for definable $S_{n-1}$-indexed families in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Could you say precisely what theory is "$(n+1)$-th order arithmetic"?

Comment: It's debatable but what I wrote in the second paragraph is pretty standard. The sort $N$ satisfies basic arithmetic ($0,1,+,\times$) with induction for all formulas (including formulas that involve quantifiers or parameters of higher sorts). Full comprehension for each set sort $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ (again, for all formulas). I think some would include some choice, in particular choice over $N$, but Colin specifically asked  about omitting choice.

Comment: And, of course, the set sorts are required to satisfy extensionality. Technically, they don't have to be actual sets, we just have membership relations $\in_i$ from $S_{i-1}$ to $S_i$, but with extensionality we may as well assume that they consist of actual sets.

Comment: The argument gives a little more than just $\mathrm{Z}_{n-1}^-$. Namely, the Mostowski Beta axiom (every extensional wellfounded relation on a set has a Mostowski collapse) is valid in $\mathcal{V}$. This gives a little bit of replacement but not much.

Comment: This is the right technology, but I do not think it will give replacement without considerations of constructibility and hereditary constructible countability and its analogues to make each higher order correspond to one higher cardinal.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty This kind of technology, which I presume is similar to Zbierski's, won't do that. To get replacement in $\mathcal{V}$, you need something really close to choice. Basically, you need that for every definable relation $R \subseteq S_{n-1} \times S_n$ contains a definable subrelation $R'$ with size at most $S_{n-1}$. When $n = 1$, this is equivalent to countable choice. More generally, if $S_{n-1}$ is wellordered with size $\kappa$ this is equivalent to choice for families of size at most $\kappa$.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais More than that I believe you need the control over cardinality that constructibility gives, just as Simpson does for the case of 2nd order arithmetic and ZF[0] in SOSOA.  And this is complicated in higher orders because to put it naively $n+2$ order arithmetic tells you what (not necessarily constructible) $\beth_n$ is but when $n>0$ this tells you nothing about how far from constructible $\beth_n$ that may be.